# Bamboo builder task

Tags: bamboo

I am a newbie for CI & now start using Bamboo server for continuous integration. I've just get running Bamboo server and set first plan. I set the task for source checkout. Now I am trying to add automated build for my app.

For now app is just simple console based example running both at windows and linux. I have makefile associated with app to build it and then I run *.exe (win) or ./* (linux) manually.

Now I want to set the "Builder task" (script task), how do I automatize it building it with Bamboo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add "Script task" and call your makefile to build your application in it. You also would need to define an Artifact - providing relative path to your .exe file. (Artifacts tab within your job configuration, [more info here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-job-s-build-artifacts-289277071.html)) so you can download your .exe file when the build is finished.

Comment: is there any example for  "Windows builder task" aka "hello_world"

Comment: how do you build your app currently on your local machine? theoretically you should be able to build it the same way with Bamboo (with Windows agent)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you bamboo is running 
If the Bamboo is on linux machine , just script task would be enough . To build it on windows environment as well , you need to have windows agent or use winexe to call it remotely .